# I have an error in my Django accounts app

Tags: python, django

I was following the tutorial on https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/series/2017/09/25/a-complete-beginners-guide-to-django-part-4.html and I have an error message which says that account_views is not defined. In my urls.py file which is located in C:\Users\vitorfs\Development\myproject\myproject\myproject.  Here is the code

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin

from accounts import views as account_views
from boards import views


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^signup/$', accounts_views.signup, name='signup'),
    url(r'^boards/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.board_topics, name='board_topics'),
    url(r'^boards/(?P<pk>\d+)/new/$', views.new_topic, name='new_topic'),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

The error is on line 25, url(r'^signup/$', accounts_views.signup, name='signup'), which states that account_views is not defined.  I would like to know why I am getting this error, and also, can you show me how to fix this error?

Comment: It is `account_views`, not `accounts_views`.

Comment: Thanks.  I added the s to account_views and I got another error which states that module accounts.views has no attribute named signup.  Can you show me how to fix this error?

Comment: then likely you did not define a function `def signup` in your `views.py`.

Comment: @AlfredTsang please show your views.py

Comment: I am still having problems with this Django thing.  I changed it to account_views and it still gives me the error.  I am extremely frustrated right now.  Can you show me how to solve this problem?

Comment: What type of error do you get?

Comment: NameError: name 'account_view' is not defined.

Comment: The error has been fixed.  Thank you all of you.

Comment: Please explain what you did so that anyone else who encountered this problem can fix it.

Comment: What I did was I went into my accounts/views.py and added this to it.


from django.shortcuts import render

def signup(request):
    return render(request, 'signup.html')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are importing the accounts in the top of the file, you are saying `from accounts import views as account_views`. You are importing it as `account_views` so in your urls, you should say account_views not accounts_views.